# Eclipse CDT jni.h not found

Tags: eclipse, java-native-interface, eclipse-cdt

I'm using Eclipse CDt and I've got a generated .h file using Makefile.
It could't resolve **#include** .
Any suggestion?

Comment: You missing the -I./path/to/header in your compiler arguments.  That flag maybe different between compilers, consult your documentation for C/C++ include paths.

Comment: I've tryed to add path in properties>>C/C++ General>>Paths and Symbols>>Includes directories, and also in make file `gcc -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\include\win32"` but when I try to build, I'll receive "fatal error: jni.h: No such file or direcotry"

Comment: -I is not delimited by the Java path separator.  You need a separate argument for each path.  Additionally, your javah generated headers are not in the JDK path, they will (hopefully) be local to your project.  I highly recomend you take a look at the documentation https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html and https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-Headers.html#System-Headers

Comment: @Alex Barker solved with `gcc -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\include\win32"`, thanks